Lebesgue integral and inequality with modules
Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, with $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure and consider a function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^N, \quad f=(f_1,f_2,...,f_N)$ where $N\in\mathbb{N^\ast}$. Suppose that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, then
$$\left|\int_X f\ d\mu\right|\leq \int_X|f|\ d\mu$$
Proof.
If $\int_X f\ d\mu =0$, there's nothing to prove. Suppose that $\int_X f\ d\mu \ne 0$, we have:
$$\left|\int_X f\ d\mu\right|=\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \left|\int_X f_j\ d\mu\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\overset{(a)}{=} \sum_{j=1}^N \left[\left|\int_X f_j\ d\mu\right|\cdot \frac{\left|\int_X f_j\ d\mu\right|}{\left(\sum_{m=1}^N \left|\int_X f_m\ d\mu\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]\leq$$
$$\leq \sum_{j=1}^N \left[\int_X |f_j|\ d\mu\cdot \frac{\left|\int_X f_j\ d\mu\right|}{\left(\sum_{m=1}^N \left|\int_X f_m\ d\mu\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]\overset{(b)}{=}$$ $$\overset{(b)}{=}\int_X \left[\sum_{j=1}^N |f_j|\cdot \frac{\left|\int_X f_j\ d\mu\right|}{\left(\sum_{m=1}^N \left|\int_X f_m\ d\mu\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]\ d\mu \overset{(c)}{\leq}$$
$$\overset{(c)}{\leq} \int_X\left(\sum_{j=1}^N |f_j|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{|\int_X f_j\ d\mu|^2}{\sum_{m=1}^N \left|\int_X f_m\  d\mu\right|^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ d\mu=\int_X|f|\ d\mu$$
where $(c)$ follows from
$\sum_{j=1}^N|a_jb_j|\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^N |a_j|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^N |b_j|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
I can't understand why $(a)$ holds and why the switch between integral and sum in $(b)$ is allowed. Thanks for your help.

For $(a)$, it's because for any positive number $x$ we have
$$\sqrt{x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
For $(b)$ they just use the linearity of the Lebesgue integral:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^N a_j \int_X f_j d\mu = \int_X  \sum_{j = 1}^N a_j f_j d\mu$$
where $a_j$ here are
$$a_j = \frac{|\int_X f_j\ d\mu|}{\sum_{m=1}^N \left|\int_X f_m\  d\mu\right|^2}.$$
